# How to ggregate two collections and match field with array

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I need to group the results of two collections `candidatos` and `ofertas`, and then "merge" those groups to return an array with matched values.

I've created this example with the aggregate and similar data to make this easier to test:

https://mongoplayground.net/p/m0PUfdjEye4

This is the explanation of the problem that I'm facing.

I can get both groups with the desired results independently:

**candidatos collection:**

```
db.getCollection('ofertas').aggregate([
{"$group" : {_id:"$ubicacion_puesto.provincia", countProvinciaOferta:{$sum:1}}} 
 ]);
```

This is the result...

[image]

**ofertas collection:**

```
db.getCollection('candidatos').aggregate([
{"$group" : {_id:"$que_busco.ubicacion_puesto_trabajo.provincia", countProvinciaCandidato:{$sum:1}}} 
 ]);
```

This is the result...

[image]

What I need to do, is to aggregate those groups to merge their results based on their _id coincidence. I think I'm going in the right way with the next aggregate, but the field `countOfertas` always returns `0.0`. I think that there is something wrong in my `project $cond`, but I don't know what is it. This is the aggregate:

```
db.getCollection('candidatos').aggregate([
    {"$group" : {_id:"$que_busco.ubicacion_puesto_trabajo.provincia", countProvinciaCandidato:{$sum:1}}},
    
            {
            $lookup: {
                from: 'ofertas',
                let: {},
                pipeline: [
                    {"$group" : {_id:"$ubicacion_puesto.provincia", countProvinciaOferta:{$sum:1}}} 
                ],
                as: 'ofertas'
            }
        },
     
       {
    $project: {
        _id: 1,
        countProvinciaCandidato: 1,
      countOfertas: {
          $cond: {
            if: {
              $eq: ['$ofertas._id', "$_id"]
            },
            then: '$ofertas.countProvinciaOferta',
            else: 0,
          }
      }
    }
  },   
        { $sort: { "countProvinciaCandidato": -1}},
        { $limit: 20 }
 ]);
```

And this is the result, but as you can see, field `countOfertas` is always 0

[image]

Any kind of help will be welcome

Comment: You have given us the mongo playground which is awesome. But try to avoid posting images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have tried is so much appreciated. But in `$project` you need to use `$reduce` which helps to loop through the array and satisfy the condition

Here is the code

```
db.candidatos.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      _id: "$que_busco.ubicacion_puesto_trabajo.provincia",
      countProvinciaCandidato: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "ofertas",
      let: {},
      pipeline: [
        {
          "$group": {
            _id: "$ubicacion_puesto.provincia",
            countProvinciaOferta: { $sum: 1 }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "ofertas"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      countProvinciaCandidato: 1,
      countOfertas: {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$ofertas",
          initialValue: 0,
          "in": {
            $cond: [
              { $eq: [ "$$this._id", "$_id" ] },
              { $add: [ "$$value", 1 ] },
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $sort: { "countProvinciaCandidato": -1 } },
  { $limit: 20 }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0dczc-sDIMx)**

Note : If you need to do with aggregations only, this is fine. But I personally feel this approach is not good. My suggestion is, you can concurrently call group aggregations in different service and do it with programmatically. Because `$lookup` is expensive, when you get massive data, this performance will be reduced

Comment: Many thanks for your response varman. You were too close but your aggregate returned 0 or 1 in the countOfertas field. I edited your response to make it the correct response. I changed the $add to return countProvinciaOferta. I also added  a $match to delete the null value.

Answer (score 1):

The `$eq` in the `$cond` is comparing an array to an ObjectId, so it never matches.

The `$lookup` stage results will be in the `ofertas` field as an array of documents, so `'$ofertas._id'` will be an array of all the _id values.

You will probably need to use `$unwind`, `$reduce` after the `$lookup`.